# R mingw multiple definition of `typeinfo for std::exception'

Tags: mingw, rcpp

I am trying to compile the following code with Rcpp

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
using namespace Rcpp;

// parallelization test
void workerFunc()
{

  boost::posix_time::seconds workTime(3);
  std::cout << "Worker: Running" << '\n';
  //boost::this_thread::sleep(workTime);
  double k=1;
  for (int i = 1; i<100000000; ++i)
    k = k*sqrt(i);
  std::cout<< "Worker: Finished" << '\n';
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]  
void parallelTests() {
  // creates threads and joins them
  std::vector<boost::thread *> z;

  for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
    z.push_back(new boost::thread(workerFunc));

  for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
  {
    z[i]->join();
    delete z[i];
  }
}
```

getting the following errors

```
g++ -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o sourceCpp_5.dll tmp.def CppThreadTest.o -L C:/mingw/MinGW/lib -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.4/bin/x64 -lR
C:/mingw/MinGW/lib/libstdc++.a(stdexcept.o):stdexcept.cc:(.rdata$_ZTISt9exception[_ZTISt9exception]+0x0): multiple definition of `typeinfo for std::exception'
CppThreadTest.o:CppThreadTest.cpp:(.data$_ZTISt9exception[_ZTISt9exception]+0x0): first defined here
C:/mingw/MinGW/lib/libstdc++.a(stdexcept.o):stdexcept.cc:(.rdata$_ZTISt13runtime_error[_ZTISt13runtime_error]+0x0): multiple definition of `typeinfo for std::runtime_error'
CppThreadTest.o:CppThreadTest.cpp:(.data$_ZTISt13runtime_error[_ZTISt13runtime_error]+0x0): first defined here
C:/mingw/MinGW/lib/libstdc++.a(bad_alloc.o):bad_alloc.cc:(.rdata$_ZTISt9bad_alloc[_ZTISt9bad_alloc]+0x0): multiple definition of `typeinfo for std::bad_alloc'
CppThreadTest.o:CppThreadTest.cpp:(.data$_ZTISt9bad_alloc[_ZTISt9bad_alloc]+0x0): first defined here
C:/mingw/MinGW/lib/libstdc++.a(eh_exception.o):eh_exception.cc:(.rdata$_ZTISt13bad_exception[_ZTISt13bad_exception]+0x0): multiple definition of `typeinfo for std::bad_exception'
```

My boost installation is coming with the mingw from the following distribution [MINGW Distro](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html)

I set the Paths within R, and compile

```
Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-I C:/mingw/MinGW/include")
Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS"="-L C:/mingw/MinGW/lib")
Rcpp::sourceCpp('C:/temp/kvasvn/kva/CppThreadTest.cpp', verbose=TRUE)
```

Do you know what might be causing this?

Edit 1:

Ok first error was caused by C:/mingw/MinGW/lib directory containing other version of the libstdc. I just copied libboost_thread.a to C:/mingw/MinGW/myFolder and included that. Now having other errors

```
g++ -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o sourceCpp_11.dll tmp.def CppThreadTest.o -L C:/mingw/MinGW/myFolder -lboost_thread -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.4/bin/x64 -lR
C:/mingw/MinGW/myFolder/libboost_thread.a(thread.o):thread.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN5boost6system12system_errorE[_ZTVN5boost6system12system_errorE]+0x0): multiple definition of `vtable for boost::system::system_error'
CppThreadTest.o:CppThreadTest.cpp:(.data$_ZTVN5boost6system12system_errorE[_ZTVN5boost6system12system_errorE]+0x0): first defined here
C:/mingw/MinGW/myFolder/libboost_thread.a(thread.o):thread.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_baseE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_baseE]+0x0): multiple definition of `vtable for boost::exception_detail::clone_base'
CppThreadTest.o:CppThreadTest.cpp:(.data$_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_baseE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_baseE]+0x0): first defined here
C:/mingw/MinGW/myFolder/libboost_thread.a(thread.o):thread.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTVN5boost9exceptionE[_ZTVN5boost9exceptionE]+0x0): multiple definition of `vtable for boost::exception'
```

Where is the other definition of boost::system::system_error, I dont understand?

Comment: In general, you will want to rebuild _every_ library you use with the compiler provided by/for R.  In general you _cannot_ swap in a different MinGW.

Comment: How do you suggest building boost thread library within R?

Comment: I guess other option is to not use boost thread but try [TinyThread](http://tinythreadpp.bitsnbites.eu/doc/) supposed to be header only library, will try later

Comment: Or just use RcppParallel which wraps Intel TBB for you (which is more powerful than TinyThread -- it used to contain it for Windoze).   As for 'how do I build a library for Windows':  well, among the 8000+ CRAN packages you will find some examples.  From the top of my head RBGL wraps part of Boost Graph.   But using RcppParallel will easier and more portable.

Comment: Yes, looked into that. Not using RcppParallel since the aim for my C++ code library is also be able to work independent from R. Using Rcpp just to expose certain functions of the code library